# Finding common data sets and journey paths

Tags: php, mysql

I have thousands of data objects. Each a user's journey through a website. Each with data on each page they went to and in what order. I want to be able to find the common paths through the site.

I.e

```
User 1
    Page 1
    Page 2
    Page 3
    Page 4
User 2
    Page 1
    Page 2
    Page 4
User 3
    Page 3
    Page 5
User 4
    Page 1
    Page 2
    Page 5
    Page 4
```

The most common path is P1, P2, P4 (even though some went to additional pages as well)

I was thinking of storing in mysql but can't work out the query, so not even sure how to store the table? Otherwise i would normalise it.

Or maybe the calculation would have to be in PHP and i cant do any sort of calculation in PHP to work it out?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @strawberry My question is about what the structure of the MYSQL would be and if its even posisble so i dont even know what an MCRE would be?

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted to store this as follows:

```
id user page
```

This tells us everything we need to know. However, SQL is not good at this kind of analysis, but note that looking for common sequences in strings is exactly what DNA researchers do (and they have to mine truly vast amounts of data), so I would look to see how they do it, and copy that.